# express, jade, node.js, coffeescript, setting up routes using an array of variables and a for loop

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, pug

I just inherited a project with node.js/express written in coffeescript and using jade to render views. In my views folder I have about 20 jade files that need to have routes set up. Rather than repeat myself over and over like so (which is currently working just fine):

```
app.get '/html/404.html', (req,res) ->
  res.render '404',

app.get '/html/503.html', (req,res) ->
  res.render '503', 

app.get '/html/foo.html', (req,res) ->
  res.render 'foo',
```

I'd prefer to keep this less messy by creating an array of the urls and using a for loop to iterate over it, something like this:

```
urls = [
  "404"
  "503"
  "foo"
]

for url in urls
  app.get "/html/#{url}.html", (req,res) ->
    res.render "#{url}",
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Any advice?

Comment: what exactly isn't working, are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem that happens when you define a closure in a loop in JavaScript: You expect the value of `url` in your route function to be whatever it was when you defined that function, but in fact, it's whatever the last value in the loop was. There's only one `url` variable, after all.

The fix is to "capture" that variable in an outer closure, which is why CoffeeScript has the `do` syntax:

```
for url in urls
  do (url) ->
    app.get "/html/#{url}.html", (req,res) ->
      res.render "#{url}"
```

For more on this, see my PragPub article [A CoffeeScript Intervention](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention).

(Having said this, Arnaud's suggestion of using an Express param in the route is a much more elegant solution. If you can avoid a loop entirely, do so!)

Comment: Thanks Trevor! I was just about to post the same answer from my coworker regarding this. Another related article: http://rzrsharp.net/2011/06/27/what-does-coffeescripts-do-do.html

Answer (score 1):

Quick response :

```
for url in urls
  app.get "/html/#{url}.html", (req,res) ->
    res.render req.params.url
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response but this doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Arnaud, you're confusing CoffeeScript's string interpolation with Express' param interpolation, which would be something like `"/html/:url"`.